# Transferring Calls between FreeSWITCH and Session Manager

Tags: freeswitch

Transferring Calls between FreeSWITCH and Session Manager

We have a Avaya Session Manager and a FreeSWITCH as a feature Server connected with it.

- Call from the Avaya CM World routed to the FreeSWITCH via Avaya Session Manager.
- In FreeSWITCH we do some processing (replace the Caller ID) and
- send it back to the Session Manager

FreeSWITCH handles the Call the as follows

Call come from SM 1.2.3.4

- a dialplan calls a lua script 
  ** dnis may be 19131913
- this lua script does the processing (db lookup, and so on ...)
- finally it calls `session:transfer("tosm" .. dnis, "XML", "AS5850")`; to transfer the call
- a dialplan matching tosm19131913 does a bridge back to SM 1.2.3.4

```xml
<extension name="AVAYA SM">
   <condition field="destination_number" expression="^tosm(\d*)$">
      <action application="bridge" data="sofia/AS5850/0*$1@1.2.3.4"/>
   </condition>
</extension>
```

This works relatively fine but the problem is that FS still holds the call with two channels as long as the call exists. This consumes two channels on the Session Manager wich is expensive.

It is possible on FreeSWITCH commandline to drop the channels so that the call leaves the FS completely. The command to do this is uuid_simplify.

I've tried to execute that command from lua script with

```
  my_fs_api = freeswitch.API()
  my_exec_result = my_fs_api:executeString("sofia status")
  my_exec_result = my_fs_api:executeString("uuid_simplify " .. my_ssession_uuid)
  freeswitch.consoleLog("notice","\n\n[1c]   result " .. my_exec_result .. "\n\n")
```

but it does not work.

I've tried to remove `session:tranfer` from session transfer and use deflect on the dialplan. This also dosn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're simply using the wrong tool. If you only need to modify the SIP headers, such as caller ID, you can easily go with Kamailio and configure it for stateless processing, so that it doesn't need to know about ongoing sessions.

I could help with some consulting in January (currently fully booked for the rest of the year)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Statinslav. I think i'ts worth looking at Kamailio or maybe OpenSIPS. But the customer says "oh no! not another tool" on the short run we'll handle the problem with brute force a.k.a. licenses. I do not set this as answered because I'm still hoping for a solution in FreeSWITCH.

Comment: you can try with media bypass mode in FreeSWITCH, but as far as I understand the problem, it will not help too much.

Comment: acceptiong this answer because I think there is no better solution if you're looking for a tool. Another way is to develop a simple SIP Servlet with a container like Mobicents.

Comment: here's a small Kamailio config that I've done for a customer. You can base your own on something similar:  https://github.com/voxserv/kamailio-static-relay

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the command [deflect of FreeSWITCH](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_deflect) that will execute a SIP REFER to complete transferring the call and the call will leave FreeSWITCH.